# Redirection from a static method Symfony2?

Tags: php, methods, static, redirect, symfony

```
static public function check( $securityContext)
{   
    $user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

  if(is_object($user) && [...])
    return **$this**->redirect(**$this**->generateUrl('route_recruteur_monespace'));



    return $user->getRecruteur();
}
```

I tried with new Controller()-> but it doesn't work, so how can i call redirect() from a static method.
thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass the services required to the static method

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class Foo
{
    static public function check($securityContext, $router)
    {
        $user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

        // ...

        return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('route_name'));
    }
}
```

You can then call it in your controller

```php
Foo::check($this->get('security.context'), $this->get('router'));
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router::generateUrl()